# How to use extracted text from subsearch in the Parent search

Tags: splunk-query

The sub query `search command | rex field=_raw "employeeid=(?<empid>[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)" | return empid` returns the result:

empid="d8666160-eaf4-4943-a661-60eaf4894357"

Now I want to do one more search using the value of employeeid field:
`app="appname" AND "some text" AND "d8666160-eaf4-4943-a661-60eaf4894357"`

How can I do this? I was trying to fix the below query but did not succeed.

`app="appname" AND "some text" AND [search command | rex field=_raw "employeeid=(?<empid>[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)" | return empid]`

I don't want to search with the field name in the Parent query but only use the field value from the sub query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `join` command

```
parent query search
| rex "extract field" 
| rename field as empid 
| join empid 
    [ search child query search 
    | rex "extract child field"
    | rename childfield as empid]
```